# Visual Studio 2008 - formatting/control characters/marks

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I don't know what I did but somehow the IDE has started displaying a green dot whenever I press spacebar and a green arrowhead whenever I press TAB. The source has become littered with these characters all over and I am finding it very difficult to code in the presence of so many formatting marks. I have tried to search a solution on Google but couldn't perhaps enter the right keywords so haven't been able to fix the behavior.

Is there any way I can stop VS2008 IDE from littering my source code with these green dots and arrowheads whenever I press spacebar/tab?

I would be really thankful for this help.

Thanks,

-AL
PS: Re-posting the question as I am new to this forum and probably couldn't see the email notification option earlier. My apologies for this inconvenience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show space, tab, CRLF characters in editor of Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255839/show-space-tab-crlf-characters-in-editor-of-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Edit Menu->Advanced->View White Space or CTRL+E,S

Answer (score 2):

Press ***Ctrl R, W***

See **[How to enable Visible White Space?](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/03/21/399811.aspx)**

Comment: thats the 2003 and 2005 keystroke...not the 2008