# When I use the tab, there is right arrow on the code page in visual studio 2010

Tags: tabs

Create a right arrow on the code table, when I use the tab key in visual stdio 2010. How can I fix-it?

SS URL: http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/189/1b1g.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing white space characters. [Edit → Advanced → View White Space or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to toggle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255942/139010)

Answer (score 1):

Click on Edit-->Advanced-->View White Space to toggle the white space characters on/off.  Pressing Ctrl+E, S will also toggle white space on/off.