# Show spaces as tabs in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, spaces, tabstop

I need to use spaces instead of tabs and unfortunately I can't explain Visual Studio 2013 to show every 4 spaces as tab-stop.
Example:

```
def hello():
....for i in range(3):
........print('Hello world!')
```

but i need something like

```
def hello():
...|for i in range(3):
...|...|print('Hello world!')
```

I mean i don't need exactly vertical line character, just somehow distinguish indents.

By the way Geany IDE makes it great.

**EDIT:**
Visual Studio does show me spaces, it doesn't show vertical lines.

Comment: Please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255839/show-space-tab-crlf-characters-in-editor-of-visualstudio

Comment: It seems I didn't express myself clearly. Please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i have found solution: you need to install "Indent Guides" extension to VS.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Productivity Power Tools for VS2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) and than you can find these options in the edit > advanced menu.